# Read Nexus 2.x logs using REST

Tags: rest, nexus2

Is it possible to read the Nexus 2.14 log (the one you see in Administration -> Logging) per http access (REST)?

If not, are there other means to read it from an external program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an option to download the logs from the `Log` tab in Nexus.

[image: Nexus - Download logs]]

Once you have downloaded the file, your browser will capture the URL from where it was downloaded, which will be listed in the downloads section of your browser.

[image: Download URL]

You can use the below methods to fetch the logs,

- Fetching the logs using `curl`:

  ```
  curl -u uname:pass http://nexusURL/nexus/service/siesta/logging/log
  ```
- Fetching the logs in `Node.js` using the [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module:

  ```
  var request = require('request')

  var opts = {
      headers: { Authorization: "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" },   //For admin:admin
      uri: 'http://nexusURL/nexus/service/siesta/logging/log',
      method: "GET"
  }
  request(opts,function(err, res, body){
          console.log(body)
      }
  );
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/siesta/logging/log
```

gives you the recent log file (found by trial and error).